# play button sound without stopping music running in the background

Tags: c++, winapi

I use `PlaySound(TEXT("background.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);` to play music in the background. I have some buttons in my game that play a short sound when the user clicks the button and it will stop the music. How can I keep the music playing in the whole game? I use `PlaySound(TEXT("button.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);` for the button sound.

Comment: PlaySound is not suitable for playing music.

Comment: See [Audio and Video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/audio-and-video).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have some buttons in my game that play a short sound when the user
> clicks the button and it will stop the music.

You can use `PlaySound` to play background music in a loop. Then use [mciSendString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757161(v=vs.85)) to play a short sound.

Like this:

```
//play music in the background
PlaySound(TEXT("background.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
...

//Press Button 1
mciSendString(L"close Sound_1", NULL, 0, NULL);//need to close first
LPCWSTR const Sound_File_1 = L"open button.wav type mpegvideo alias Sound_1";
mciSendString(Sound_File_1, NULL, 0, NULL);
MCIERROR play = mciSendString(L"play Sound_1", NULL, 0, NULL);

//Press Button 2
mciSendString(L"close Sound_2", NULL, 0, NULL);//need to close first
LPCWSTR const Sound_File_2 = L"open button_2.wav type mpegvideo alias Sound_2";
mciSendString(Sound_File_2, NULL, 0, NULL);
MCIERROR play = mciSendString(L"play Sound_2", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

You can also use `mciSendString` to play background music in a loop, depending on your needs.

```
WCHAR str[] = L"background.wav";          
LPCWSTR const Sound_File = L"open background.wav type mpegvideo alias Sound";
mciSendString(Sound_File, NULL, 0, NULL);
MCIERROR play = mciSendString(L"play Sound repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);
```