# How to fix mciSendString() delay?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I was trying to add some sound effects to my game using `mciSendString()` function, but there was a huge fps drop every time I called this function in game. I tried using another function `PlaySound()`, it fixed the delay, but this function lacks the possibility of playing two sounds at the same time. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: mci and Playsound are as legacy at it gets.  Google for [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction) or DirectSound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play button sound without stopping music running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734142/play-button-sound-without-stopping-music-running-in-the-background)